# Problemas de estilos css en DOMPDF Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Tengo una consulta sobre esta librería `DOMPDF` de Laravel para generar documentos pdf, resulta que a través de ello estoy generando un recibo como factura al cliente, lo cual no tengo problemas para crearlo, mi problema radica cuando quiero darle estilos a este blade ya que le cree su propio css y **estilos bootstrap** pero no lee ningun estilo, sin embargo si esta página con el mismo formato lo llevo a un index normal funciona agarra todos los estilos que he creado, no se si estoy obviando algo o se tiene que hacer mención a algo para que al momento de pasarlo a pdf agarre los estilos css:
Agrego las imagenes para que se pueda entender.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no pongas el código en forma de imagen, dale editar y añade el texto

Comment: Buenas noches, tengo entendido que esa libreria tiene problemas con el uso de los estilos extras, yo cuando me toco trabajar tuve que hacer todo el css en el head del documento. Osea aplique los estilos personalizados.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, exactamente si lo agrego en el head el estilo funciona, no existe alguna documentacion para agregar estilo a traves del dompdf?

Comment: Intenta añadiendo el css en el mismo documento donde tienes la estructura html.
Anteriormente tuve problemas similares, el problema radica que no puedes especificar mediante el DOM la ruta donde se encuetran tus archivos css

Answer (score -1):

para los que aun no han econtrado solucion
e aqui la respuesta

```php
<?php
$nombreImagen = "./arriba.jpg";
$imagenBase64 = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($nombreImagen));

<img src="<?php echo $imagenBase64 ? alt="" style="width:100px">
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -2):

Tienes que poner en el head todo tu código css, de lo contrario no funcionaría.

En lo particular uso muy frecuentemente esta librería, y no me funciona con archivos externos. Entonces lo que hago es usar `css` nativo dentro del layout que voy a usar, ejemplo dentro de la etiqueta `head`:

```
<style>
    .master
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    th
    {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid #006ac1;
        background-color: #00AEEF;
        color: #ffffff;
    }    
</style>
```

Si te puedes dar cuenta me funcionan clases y demas, intenta con este ejemplo.

Comment: pues si revisas, de hecho ahi es donde lo tiene declarado

Comment: No lo importes, ósea no utilices un archivo externo sino que tienes que escribir el `css` nativo dentro de las etiquetas `head`

Comment: agrega el por que de tu afirmación a la respuesta

Comment: Porque yo así lo he trabajado y funciona al 100%, otra cosa las clases de bootstrap no las acepta!

Comment: por eso amigo, revisa [answer] las explicaciones de tu respuesta van en la misma respuesta, dale editar y añade todas estas razones